# multiple Image download after selecting

Tags: php, image, download

This is pushan once again .I have a applied a code  to download multiple pictures after selecting them through check boxes. the value property of the check box contains the full path of the image .The image file is not downloading here is the code snippet:

```
if(isset($_POST['picdnld'])) {
    $picarry=$_POST['supplier_picture'];
    foreach($picarry as $pic) {
        $handle = fopen($pic, "r");  
        $filename1 = basename($pic); 
        $xt=pathinfo($pic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $filename=$filename1;
        echo $filename.'</br>';

        $outhandle=fopen('image'."/".$filename,"w");

        if($outhandle){
            echo 'directory found'.'</br>';
        } else {
            echo "directory not found".'</br>';
        }

        while (!feof($handle)) {  
            $buffer=fread($handle,4096);  
            fputs($outhandle,$buffer);  
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
    fclose($outhandle);
}
```

supplier picture is the name of the checkbox whose post contains the image links.I found that `$outhandle` is returning false every time. please help me to down load multiple selected images.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible the way you show. A response can generally contain only one image resource.

The most common way of doing this is to put all images into a ZIP file, and offer that for download. You could use the [`ZipArchive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php) class for that. The linked page contains a small example.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the image file and before sending it to browser
set the content header before sending to browser 
`header ("Content-Type: image/jpeg")`.

Comment: yes for sure he can send single picture in one request, @pushan use the lib described by @Pekka and then set header to `applicaion/zip` before sending zip file.